# Transfer or copy Gnome to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I was wondering if there is a way to import/clone/restore my gnome configuration from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04.

Both Ubuntu sit on two different HD installed in the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

This ishad to run off and double check what you where going to need to look for.

Your personal gnome settings are located in 'hidden' directories in you home drive.
They are as follows:
`~/.gnome
~/.gnome2
~/.nautilus
~/.gconf`

The ~ indicates the users home drive.

So now you know where the settings are you have 2 options.

1. If yo have a separate partition on one of your 2 drives you should migrate your home drive to it.
   Then on each of the versions you need to point the system to this part it on (read up on the config file /etc/fstab).
2. Copy the above files to alocation that is accessible from distros, and then create links to them from you home directory on each instance.

The first option is going to be better long term, as it will enable you to keep all your files and config intact between upgrades, and with your current setup you will be able to test o the new version to ensure that no 'essential' stuff is broken before you do a full migration.

The second method is good if you are using multiple versions of something, it will enable you to easily switch between old and new forms of acceptable config. So better if you are interested in developing or testing.

References.

- This [thread on the Ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=859248) for the reminder of where gnome keeps its config.
- See the [Ubuntu Fstab wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more info.
- The [how to auto mount partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) on the Ubuntu wiki may also be useful reading.

Hope that helps.

David.

Comment: Thanks David very helpful, however, in Ubuntu  12.04 I can't seem to find the nautilus folder. I checked under my home folder (after showing the hidden files) but there is nothing about nautilus.

Comment: Maybee nautilus usnt thé defalt file manager, if you dont have nautilus on either install you likely won't find the 'hidden' directory. Your best bet is to try what I suggested, just ignoring the nautilus part. If this works for you add in your own solution and accept that as you prefered answer.